# Is there a way to apply a regex find/replace in Notepad ++ to a certain number of lines at a time?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a large document that I am manually highlighting 8 lines of, and using replace (in selection) to concatenate them into one line, separated by commas for importing into a CSV.  Is there a way to apply this to the entire document, 8 lines at a time? Regex find is `(\h*\R)+` replace is `\x20,`.

If there is a better solution through another plugin or application, I am all ears!

Example:

```
MS-AP-RM-107


DHCP

10.2.54.75

MS-AP-RM-107

MS

PoE/Medium Power (15.4 W)

AIR-CAP3702I-A-K9

FCW2013NM20

HS-AP-RM-113

DHCP

10.2.54.74

HS-AP-RM-105

HS

PoE/Medium Power (15.4 W)

AIR-CAP3702I-A-K9

FCW2013NP3H
```

is turned into:

```
MS-AP-RM-107 ,DHCP ,10.2.54.75 ,MS-AP-RM-107 ,MS ,PoE/Medium Power (15.4 W) ,AIR-CAP3702I-A-K9 ,FCW2013NM20
HS-AP-RM-113 ,DHCP ,10.2.54.74 ,HS-AP-RM-105 ,HS ,PoE/Medium Power (15.4 W) ,AIR-CAP3702I-A-K9 ,FCW2013NP3H
```

Comment: There might be workarounds, but you need to provide the rules for selecting blocks of text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a single step approach, you can do it with an explicit match of the 8 lines, it's a bit ugly but it will work.

So you take the pattern that matches 1 line:

```
(.*?)(?:\h*\R)+
```

First “1” is there to match as little as possible, second one is to make the second parentheses pair a non capturing group while allowing repetition as your regex seems to group empty lines together. Remove the “+” if that is not desired.

and repeat it 8 times:

```
(.*?)(?:\h*\R)+(.*?)(?:\h*\R)+(.*?)(?:\h*\R)+(.*?)(?:\h*\R)+(.*?)(?:\h*\R)+(.*?)(?:\h*\R)+(.*?)(?:\h*\R)+(.*?)(?:\h*\R)+
```

then use the following replacement:

```
\1 ,\2 ,\3 ,\4 ,\5 ,\6 ,\7 ,\8\n
```

It will not handle the last lines of the file if the number of lines is not a multiple of 8 lines, but I suppose you can handle them manually.

[Try it online!](https://regex101.com/r/ZFAxww/1)

Comment: Awesome, so that worked except it did not put the comma in between the new lines. Is there a way to do that? I seriously appreciate your help, you have already saved me hours of work!

Comment: Sorry I missed the comas in the question, I added them now. Note also that I used a space caracter instead of a `\x20` since that's the same thing.

Comment: Disregard, I figured it out! simply added a , instead of space between \1,\2, etc. Thanks!